# How to copy all text from InterlliJ terminal to clipboard

Tags: shell, intellij-idea, terminal

I am using OS X and trying to copy running output from InterlliJ terminal. The most simple way is to select text by drag the mouse but when there are hundreds on lines, this way become very difficult and waste of time.

On OS X terminal I can simply press Cmd+A then Cmd+C to copy all text but Cmd+A doesn't get the job done on InterlliJ terminal.

Therefore, I am asking for the way to copy all text from InterlliJ terminal to the clipboard without using mouse to drag text selection.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do u exactly refer terminal or console??

Comment: @SupunWijerathne I refer to the terminal in InterlliJ where you can type the shell command there as same as the terminal of the OS.

Comment: In IJ 14 I can simply select the text with my mouse and either use `CTRL` + `C` or `Right click` -> `Copy`. What seems to be your problem?

Comment: @Morfic when there are hundreds of lines to be selected, simply select by mouse is not easy anymore. I want  the method like select all then copy for the easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue I faced for Maven debug mode - **"mvn clean install -X"**.

It was generating around 1000 + lines. It is very difficult to copy the content as @spicydog mentioned.

To capture all build debug log, try below command -

> Command Format - "your-command" > "file-name-with-extension"
> mvn clean install -X > debug-21-02-2022.log

It will copy all the logs into the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the console (or logCat) logs to an external file you can follow the below steps,

1. Goto Run Configuration, or Debug Configuration,
2. Now click on the Logs tab,
3. Now click the checkbox "Save console output to file"
4. Select Folder and Filename where you want to output the logs.
5. Click Apply
6. Click OK to close

Now when you run your App, your logs should get saved to the external text/log file.

Answer (score -1):

Run the command from the Mac OSX terminal or Windows Command Prompt. Then click Command + A or Ctrl + A to select all the text and then click Cmnd + c or Ctrl + c to copy.